# why is this form still submitting after return false?

Tags: javascript, html

I am planning on showing/hiding divs to validate a form.
But the divs only show a split second, and then the form gets submitted...

Any ideas why?

here is the code:

```
function validateForm() {
var name = nameEmpty(document.getElementById("annonsera_name"));
if (nameEmpty(name)){return false;}
return false;
     }
function nameEmpty(fld){
    if (fld.value==0) {
        document.getElementById("annonsera_nameempty_error").style.display='block'; 
        document.getElementById("annonsera_namenotvalid_error").style.display='none';
        document.getElementById("annonsera_name").focus();
        return false;
    }
    else if (fld.value.match(alphaExp)) {
        document.getElementById("annonsera_namenotvalid_error").style.display='block';  
        document.getElementById("annonsera_name").focus();
        document.getElementById("annonsera_nameempty_error").style.display='none';  
        return false;
    }

         document.getElementById("annonsera_nameempty_error").style.display='none'; 
        document.getElementById("annonsera_namenotvalid_error").style.display='none';
    return false;

            }
```

and here is the form:

```
<form name="annonsera" id="annonsera" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" onSubmit="return validateForm();">
```

Comment: You've probably got a javascript error somewhere that is aborting the function and causing the form to submit as usual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably generating an error and therefore never returning anything.  Assuming you are using Firefox, have you checked the javascript console?

I see what looks like a problem here, where you call nameEmpty() twice - once with a field, and the other time with a (presumably?) boolean value:

```
var name = nameEmpty(document.getElementById("annonsera_name")); // Returns boolean
if (nameEmpty(name)){return false;} // Tries to pass boolean back into nameEmpty?
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a bit offtopic, but here goes...

You should really consider [JQuery Validation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation), it's nice, clean and easy to implement. I've done it a few times, and never looked back since. It sure beats the manual validation method like the one you use :)

Check out the [example](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation#Example), there really is not that much code to write, to get validation going.

In your example that would be (not tested):

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#annonsera").validate({
      rules: {
        annonsera_name: {
          required: true,
          minlength: 1
        }
      },
      messages: {
        annonsera_name: {
          required: "You need to write your name",
          minlength: jQuery.format("At least {0} characters required!")
        }
      }
    })
  });
</script>
```

There are also a lot of ways of customization through dhtml and css, check out the [options](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions).

Comment: JQuery Validation is far from been clean and nice. It still has a lot of bugs and has changed since the last 18 months at a point that few thing is not even compatible. It's a great piece of code to use but is not nice and clean.

Comment: To the extend I've used it, it's been extremely reliable and I still think the declarative way of writing one's validation rules beats manual validation any day. I haven't found any bugs yet, but haven't looked for them either.

Comment: Looking at http://plugins.jquery.com/project/issues/statistics/validate I see that there are 30 active bug reports. Quite a large number considering their average report life time (15 weeks 5 days). Nonetheless, I still recommend JQuery Validation, as long as the bugs doesn't affect your solution.